# FMLSanityChecker missing

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I just tried to setup Minecraft Forge for 1.6.4 in Intellij IDEA. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9bPZ28buCU).

However, now that I have set it up, [this is the console](http://pastebin.com/eeHkaVkb):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java" "-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\versions\1.6.4\1.6.4-natives" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\out\production\minecraft;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\versions\1.6.4\1.6.4.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\argo\argo\2.25_fixed\argo-2.25_fixed.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.2\gson-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\14.0\guava-14.0.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\lzma\lzma\0.0.1\lzma-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.8\launchwrapper-1.8.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\net\sourceforge\argo\argo\2.25\argo-2.25.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.47\bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.0\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.0\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-debug-all\4.1\asm-debug-all-4.1.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.10.2\scala-compiler-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.10.2\scala-library-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\out\production\MoreFoodMod;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\MODDING FILES\1.6.4\mcp\jars\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch --version 1.6 --tweakClass cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
May 18, 2014 6:08:21 PM net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper log
INFO: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
May 18, 2014 6:08:21 PM net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper log
INFO: Using primary tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
May 18, 2014 6:08:21 PM net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper log
INFO: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
2014-05-18 18:08:21 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Forge Mod Loader version 6.4.49.965 for Minecraft 1.6.4 loading
2014-05-18 18:08:21 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Java is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0, running on Windows 8.1:amd64:6.3, installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre
2014-05-18 18:08:21 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Managed to load a deobfuscated Minecraft name- we are in a deobfuscated environment. Skipping runtime deobfuscation
2014-05-18 18:08:21 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
2014-05-18 18:08:21 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
2014-05-18 18:08:21 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
2014-05-18 18:08:21 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
2014-05-18 18:08:21 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
2014-05-18 18:08:21 [INFO] [STDOUT] Loaded 40 rules from AccessTransformer config file fml_at.cfg
2014-05-18 18:08:22 [SEVERE] [ForgeModLoader] Unable to launch
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cpw.mods.fml.common.asm.FMLSanityChecker
        at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper.injectIntoClassLoader(CoreModManager.java:128)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:111)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cpw.mods.fml.common.asm.FMLSanityChecker
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:186)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper.injectIntoClassLoader(CoreModManager.java:117)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at cpw.mods.fml.common.asm.transformers.SideTransformer.transform(SideTransformer.java:41)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.runTransformers(LaunchClassLoader.java:274)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:172)
        ... 12 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I suspect that I missed a library dependancy, but I have no idea what one.

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apperanty it doesn't like JDK 1.8, downgrading to JDK 1.7u55 fixed it.

Comment: If that solved your problem, please mark this answer as accepted to remove it from the Unanswered Questions list.